# .htaccess hide .php without changing .php from link address

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

1) I have tried to hide .php from extensions with this code and it worked but i have to change all the url from /about/about.php to /about/about. Is there a way to make it just direct even when the link contains a .php?

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

I have to apply the above in my lib and about directories for the said to work but all other directories doesnt need have .htaccess and it works.

2) I want to get the link to remove /about/post-1 to show library/post-1 in the url when I click on the post it currently shows /about/post-1. Please can you tell me how to do...

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /about/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /library/viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: One question at a time please. Break your 2 different problems into 2 different questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: its almost the same Q only on mod_rewrite